# Angular 2 form builder template

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I'm trying to represent a form builder in my HTML Template:

```
     this.form = fb.group({
        HTTPMethod: [],

        processes: fb.group({
        Process: fb.group({
            id: []
        })
       })
```

For the HTTPMethod i'm doing it like this :

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="HTTPMethod">Http Method</label>
        <select
            ngControl="HTTPMethod" 
            #frequency="ngForm" 
            id="HTTPMethod" 
            class="form-control" 
            required>
            <option value="3"></option>
            <option *ngFor="#HTTPMethod of HTTPMethods" value="{{ HTTPMethod.label }}">
                {{ HTTPMethod.label }}
            </option>
        </select> 
    </div>
```

But the processes i couldn't represent it, i'm encountring the error :
**control.registerOnChange is not a function in [processes in ]**, here is my **processes** HTML representation:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="processes">Process List</label>
        <select
            ngControl="processes" 
            #frequency="ngForm" 
            id="processes" 
            class="form-control" required>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option *ngFor="#process of processes?.processList.list" 
            value="{{ process.id }}">
                {{ process.id }}
            </option>
        </select> 
    </div>
```

**Thank you in advance friends !!!**

Comment: I'm not sure if it was the same error message but a `setTimeout` fixed a similar error in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37821064/how-to-create-reusable-nested-subform-component-using-angularjs-2/37831833#37831833

Comment: A Plunker would help to investigate.