# Angular2 RC.1 Forms with multiple components

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

I am trying to break up a form into multiple sections, with each section having its own Component. 
The root component template has the `<form #f="ngForm">` tag but I want another component's template to contain the `<input ngControl="name">` tags.

When I do attempt this, angular throws "Template parse errors: No provider for ControlContainer"
I believe this is because the ngControl can't find a parent ngForm to attach to.

I have a  plunker of what I am hoping to accomplish. It also throws the error on load. (http://plnkr.co/edit/pLGQpJGbT6PzxA43XiQa?p=preview)

It works if I use the FormBuilder to build up the form controls in the root component and passing the relevant controlGroup to the child component but I am wondering if there is a way of doing this cleaner.

Comment: Sounds like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37821064/how-to-create-reusable-nested-subform-component-using-angularjs-2/37831833#37831833