# Angular2 template driven sub form component with validation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, angular, typescript

I have a template driven form which contains a group of inputs contained within an `ngFor`.

I am trying to separate the 'sub group' which repeats into its own child component, but I am having trouble having the parent `ngForm` include the validation included within the child component.

Here is a simplified version of what I am talking about:

**Parent template**:

```
<form #parentForm="ngForm">
    <input name="firstName" ngModel required>
    <input name="lastName" ngModel required>

    <child-component *ngFor="let child of children;"></child-component>
</form>
```

**Child template**:

```
<div>
    <input name="foo" required ngModel>
    <input name="bar" required ngModel>
</div>
```

I am not able to have the parent form pick up on the `required`'s of the child inputs. I tried having the child within its own form and passing the `#parentForm` instance through to the child, and having the child call:

`this.parentForm.addFormGroup(this.childForm.form)`

but this still doesn't work.

I have also child doing this the reverse way where the parent gets the `ContentChildren` of the sub forms and adds each one to the form, but still the validation doesn't work.

I know I could have the subcomponent implement `ControlValueAccessor` but then I would need to implement a custom validator which I'd rather not do since none of the validation is actually new, it's just `required`'s.

Please help me figure out why I can't add a sub-form to the parent and have it use the child's validations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution might be addition controls from child component to parent form as follows:

**child.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: `
   <div>
    <input name="foo" required ngModel>
    <input name="bar" required ngModel>
  </div>
  `
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @ViewChildren(NgModel) controls: QueryList<NgModel>;

  constructor(private parentForm: NgForm) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.controls.forEach((control: NgModel) => {
      this.parentForm.addControl(control);
    });
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/WVmY3ne4Lz1zDrqCbeg9?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use property binding and @Input for your problem which looks as

```
<form #parentForm="ngForm">
    <input name="firstName" ngModel required>
    <input name="lastName" ngModel required>

    <child-component #parentForm.childForm="ngForm" [children]="children"></child-component>
</form>
```

In your

1. Declare a input variable as

   ```
   @Input() children:any[]=[];
   ```
2. Modify the template as below

   ```
   <div *ngFor="let child of children;">
      <input name="foo" required [(ngModel)]="child.foo"/>
   </div>
   ```

Comment: That does not solve the problem. The parent component's `valid` state is still not affected by the inputs in the child component.

Comment: check the modified one

Comment: That doesn't work. I appreciate the help, but please try and make sure your answer is tested or you have a very strong reason to believe it should work.